# How to create index on table which is partitioned?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

How to create an index on a partitioned table in PostgreSQL 11.2?

My table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sometablename
(
    column1 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    column2 integer NOT NULL,
    column3 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    avg_val double precision,
    max_val double precision,
    min_val double precision,
    p95_val double precision,
    sample_count double precision,
    sum_val double precision,
    unit character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT testtable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, column3, "timestamp", user_id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH (user_id) 
    WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX testtable_unique_pkey
ON sometablename USING btree (column1 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", column2
COLLATE pg_catalog."default", "timestamp", user_id)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

As you can see `testtable_unique_pkey` is my index.

but when I run:

```sql
SELECT tablename, indexname, indexdef 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE tablename = 'sometablename'
```

I can't see my index.

I checked the explain analysis on my queries which is also not using the index.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Postgres version : 11.2

Comment: No. I did check their childs as well..no index for them as well

Comment: Just a thought: Is your table really called `table`? Because it's a reserved word in Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Actually just to hide some details I wrote it as table...let me edit it

Comment: @Dhanraj: Ok, I understand that. I was just asking for clearification because this might have thrown some error(s).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that'a a primary key constraint i.e some another table..anyway that also not coming under **SELECT tablename, indexname, indexdef 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE tablename = 'sometablename'**

Comment: Ok So therefor query plan is using primary key constrain index..ok,this answer one of my small answer..but why **SELECT tablename, indexname, indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'sometablename' ** this query now showing any index as there are two indexes...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and how to make my unique index usefull i.e should get used in query plan.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The index for the base table is never really created, so it doesn't show up in `pg_indexes`:

```
CREATE TABLE base_table
(
    column1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    column2 integer NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY HASH (user_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_one ON base_table (column1, column2, user_id);
```

So the following returns nothing:

```
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'base_table';
```

It is however stored in pg_class:

```
select i.relname as indexname, t.relname as tablename
from pg_class i
  join pg_index idx on idx.indexrelid = i.oid
  join pg_class t on t.oid = idx.indrelid
where i.relkind = 'I'
  and t.relname = 'base_table';
```

returns:

```
indexname | tablename 
----------+-----------
idx_one   | base_table
```

But for each partition the index will show up in `pg_indexes`:

```
create table st_p1 partition of base_table for values with (modulus 4, remainder 0);
create table st_p2 partition of base_table for values with (modulus 4, remainder 1);
create table st_p3 partition of base_table for values with (modulus 4, remainder 2);
create table st_p4 partition of base_table for values with (modulus 4, remainder 3);
```

And then:

```
select tablename, indexname
from pg_indexes
where tablename  in ('st_p1', 'st_p2', 'st_p3', 'st_p4');
```

returns:

```
tablename | indexname                        
----------+----------------------------------
st_p1     | st_p1_column1_column2_user_id_idx
st_p2     | st_p2_column1_column2_user_id_idx
st_p3     | st_p3_column1_column2_user_id_idx
st_p4     | st_p4_column1_column2_user_id_idx
```

---

Update 2020-06-26:

The fact that the index did not show up in `pg_indexes` was acknowledged as a bug by the Postgres team and [was fixed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.8.5.3.2) in Postgres 12.

So the above explanation is only valid for Postgres 10 and 11. Starting with Postgres 12, the index on `base_table` will be [shown](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8775ecec0c95df92b08637548061b755) in `pg_indexes.

Comment: Thanks..you are correct..As I have partition of partition , I can see indexes of subpartioned table only not master and in between node..so if consider this a tree ,so only leaf nodes will have indexes and the root and middle nodes..